# How do i send formData that consists of key value pairs and a pdf file for upload using dio?

Tags: flutter, rest, http, dio

how do i send this type of data with a pdf using dio to the backend

for example...
name: xyz,
age: 40,
certificate: xyz.pdf

All videos i met on youtube talks only about how to upload a file, none touched on how to upload a file and send other information/data at the same time

Comment: see https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/ and find `Uploading multiple files to server by FormData:` section